# Fit a linear function to multiple measurements

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

I have the data of a measurement of the same value that was repeated multiple times to decrease random noise. 
There are multiple values per input-value (time), an example could look like this:

```
Time|Measurement 1|Measurement 2|Measurement 3|Measurement 4 ...
x_t |y_t1         |y_t2         |y_t3         |y_t4
0   |value        |value        |value        |value ...
1   |value        |value        |value        |value ...
2   |value        |value        |value        |value ...
3
...
...
```

How can I find the linear function $y_t=\beta x_t +c$ that fits "best" to the data? Also, how can I then calculate the standard deviation/error on the slope and intercept?

One approach I thought of, is to just take the average of all the measurements and then perform linear regression on the average measurement but that's probably not the best method.

Comment: What are you suggesting to regress on? Do you independent values or are you suggesting to average and the apply some time series model as for example $\bar y_t = \beta \bar y_{t-1} + ...$? (do not answer in a comment ... make the question clearer)

Comment: I edited my question. Sorry, what do you mean by "independent values"? Is this a regression model?

Comment: It seems to me you have a vector $y_t$ for time $t=1,...,T$ and you perhaps want to do a regression model $y_t = x_t\beta + \epsilon_t$ here the $x_t$ are referred to as covariates or independent variables - where $y_t$ is referred to as the dependent (some prefer to call $x_t$ input variables and $y_t$ output). But it seems to me you do not mention any $x_t$ variables in your data description.

Comment: I edited the question once more. I want to find a single function, so only one $\beta$ and $\epsilon$

Comment: Well then try looking into "multivariate regression" not to be confused with "multiple regression"

Comment: If I understant it correctly, this method produces multiple variables. I only need one variable. Can I then just take the mean and standard deviation of the produced variables to get what I aimed for?

Comment: I do not know. My best suggestion was "multivariate regression".

Comment: Please search our site for threads about [repeated measures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=repeated+measures+score%3A2).

Comment: In my past experience in industrial radiation physics, we would also take repeated measurements to account for measurement variation. I personally found that either taking the averages of each measurement, or regressing the measurements as a single data set without averaging, usually gave similar fitted parameters as the measurement variation from noise was not great relative to the measured values. Regressing all of the data without averaging gave a better understanding of our work when the results were plotted with regression confidence intervals, so that is what I recommend to try first.

Comment: Ok, thank you all for your comments. I used the analytical method of linear regression and changed it a bit to allow multiple value sets. I will post my python code as an answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

I used the [analytical method of linear regression](https://www.che.udel.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/FittingData.pdf) and regressed over the data as if it was just one dataset (as proposed by James Phillips' comment on the question). I don't know if I should even post my code here since this is not stackoverflow, but it might help someone someday:

```
import numpy as np

def mult_linreg(x, y):
    if len(x) < 3:
        raise Exception("More than two datapoints required")
    sum_xy = 0
    n = 0
    sum_y = 0
    sum_x = sum(x) * len(y)
    sum_x_sq = sum(x**2) * len(y)

    for y_ in y:
        if len(y_) is not len(x):
            raise Exception("x and y dimension mismatch")
        sum_xy += np.dot(x, y_)
        n += len(y_)
        sum_y += sum(y_)
    nxsq_xsq = (n*sum_x_sq - sum_x**2)
    a = (n * sum_xy - sum_x * sum_y)/nxsq_xsq
    b = (sum_x_sq * sum_y - sum_x * sum_xy)/nxsq_xsq
    sum_y_ax_b_sq = 0
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        xi = x[i]
        axi_and_b = a*xi + b
        for y_ in y:
            yi_ = y_[i]
            sum_y_ax_b_sq += (yi_ - axi_and_b)**2

    S = np.sqrt(sum_y_ax_b_sq/(n-2))
    err_a = S * np.sqrt(n/nxsq_xsq)
    err_b = S * np.sqrt(sum_x_sq/nxsq_xsq)
    return a,b, err_a, err_b

#example
print(mult_linreg(np.array([0,6,10]),np.array([[-1,2,4],[-1.1,2.1,3.9]])))
```

The result is indeed very similar to what you get when regressing the average of all datasets, but that might depend on the input

Comment: For fitting the line when each time has the same number of measurements, this can work.  But just about all other results concerning confidence intervals, p-values, and so on, would require adjustment.  Thus, if you want to accomplish anything other than drawing a line, you would be better off investigating the tools for repeated-measures analysis.

Comment: A line is basically all I need right now, but I will look into the tools available for python. Thank you.